# How to reset CNN (Keras) model between training sessions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a modified implementation of pre-trained VGG-16 CNN (U-Net) for a task similar to image semantic segmentation. We are interested in studying the effect of training size on performance. After splitting the dataset, random images are taken from the training subset (e.g. train with 500 random images, reset model, train with 1000 random images, reset model, etc.).

The function used for resetting Keras is as follows:

```
# Function reset the model
def reset_keras(model):
    sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session() #load current TF session
    clear_session() #clear current session
    sess.close() #close current session
    sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()
    
    #try to delete the model and pass if an exception is encountered  
    try:
        del model 
    except:
        pass

    print('Number of objects collected and deallocated is', gc.collect()) # returns number of objects collected and deallocated

    # use the same config as you used to create the session
    config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto() # configure the session about to be run
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 1
    config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0" #only see gpu 0
    tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config))
```

I suspect that the model is not being correctly reset between the training sessions. For example, training with a relatively small number of images will show significantly better performance if run at the end of the session compared to the start of the session. We would like to use the same model architecture and weight initialization in all training. Only the number of training images are varied.

**What is the recommended approach for resetting the model between training sessions?**

Thank you!

Background:

- Google Colab
- The installed version of Python is: 3.7.10
- The installed version of TensorFlow is: 2.4.1
- The installed version of Keras is: 2.4.3

Comment: try recompiling the model. It should set everything back to the initial satae

Comment: Hi Gerry, good idea but unfortunately that isn’t a practical option.